# Importing a module with services provided in it

Tags: angular

If a module has services defined in the providers array and we import it in the root module, does it mean that those services will become available to all components in the application with the same instance?

For example :

The **coreModule** imports the **HttpClientModule** and then we import the **coreModule** in the **AppModule**, hence all modules imported in the AppModule will have access to the HttpClient **service**, how is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr - Yes, all components **and** descendant components in the module's descendant tree (which starts with the child components listed in the module's `declarations` array and works down) will have access to any instance of a class/dependency (like a service) that is either:

- provided directly by that module, e.g. included in `AppModule`'s `providers` array **or**
- by any other module which provides the dependency (e.g. `CoreModule`) and is imported by the module with the `declarations` array (e.g. `AppModule`)

---

Take the following example:

`test.service.ts`

```
@Injectable() // without { providedIn: 'root' }
export class TestService {
  constructor() { console.log('TestService loaded')
}
```

`test-service-providing.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [TestService],
})
export class TestServiceProvidingModule {}
```

`app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [TestServiceProvidingModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`app.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<p>App</p>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

- `TestService` is declared as `@Injectable()` but without a `providedIn` context, therefore an instance will only be able to be provided if the service is listed in a `providers` array somewhere (in an `NgModule`, a standalone component/service etc)
- `TestServiceProvidingModule` includes `TestService` in its providers array. A single instance of `TestService` is therefore available for creation. Note: The actual instance of `TestService` will only be created if any component/child component in the component tree injects `TestService` as a dependency.
- `AppModule` imports `TestServiceProvidingModule`. `AppModule` now has access to the single instance of `TestService` which originates from `TestServiceProvidingModule`

*Note: At this point you wouldn't see 'TestService loaded' displayed to the console because no component or service has injected `TestService` in its constructor. There is therefore no need for a concrete instance of `TestService` to be created.*

---

We then create a child component called `ChildComponent` and inject `TestService` into its constructor

`app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TestServiceProvidingModule,
    ChildComponent,
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `<p>Child</p>`,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}
}
```

*Note the empty `imports` array in `ChildComponent`. The only place `ChildComponent` can receive dependencies is from an ancestor*

What happens here is:

- In order to resolve the `TestService` dependency, the injection resolver first checks the component's providers and imports. `TestService` is neither declared in this component's `providers` array, nor in a module it imports
- The injection resolver then traverses up the module import tree for that component and performs the same check. It finally finds the `AppModule` which imports a module `TestServiceProviderModule`, which is able to provide a concrete instance of `TestService`
- A concrete instance of `TestService` is created and injected into `ChildComponent`
- 'TestService loaded' is displayed to the console when the constructor of this concrete instance is invoked

---

The same would be true if we created a `GrandchildComponent` and moved the dependency injection of `TestService` from `ChildComponent` to `GrandchildComponent`

`grandchild.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-grandchild',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `<p>Grandchild</p>`,
})
export class GrandchildComponent {
  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}
}
```

`child.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [GrandchildComponent],
  template: `
    <p>Child</p>
    <app-grandchild></app-grandchild>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

The same module traversal will take place, and `GrandchildComponent` will ultimately receive the instance of `TestService` that is provided by `TestServiceProvidingModule` and made available to any components (and all descendants) declared in `AppModule`'s `declarations` array

Now for the bit that ties is all together:

If we injected `TestService` into both `ChildComponent` **and** `GrandchildComponent`, we would still only see 'TestService loaded' shown in the console once. This is because it is the same instance created in `TestServiceProvidingModule` that is being injected into both child components

Comment: It is much clearer for me now, but what about the import of HttpClientModule? Does this module have a providers array that provides the HttpClient service so that when the coreModule imports it and in its turn gets imported in the root module, the service becomes available throughout the application ? Am I correct?

Comment: Yep exactly that :) Check this folder https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/main/packages/common/http/src and specifically the files `client.ts`, then `module.ts`, then `provider.ts`. `HttpClient` is an `@Injectable` class and `HttpClientModule` includes it in its `providers` array (returned from the `provideHttpClient` function)